# ActionScript - Screen Fade Performance Optimization?

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, optimization, air, fade

I'm building an AIR application that fades in on launch.  Often the window's bounds at launch is very large or in full screen.

The fade is undesirably choppy, but I've converted the vector shape into a bitmap prior to tweening the alpha property.

How can I optimize this further to achieve a smooth fade in?

```
faderFill = new Shape();
faderFill.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1.0);
faderFill.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
faderFill.graphics.endFill();

faderBitmapData = new BitmapData(faderFill.width, faderFill.height);
faderBitmapData.draw(faderFill);

faderBitmap = new Bitmap(faderBitmapData, PixelSnapping.NEVER, false);
faderBitmap.width = stage.stageWidth;
faderBitmap.height = stage.stageHeight;

addChild(faderBitmap);

Tweener.addTween(faderBitmap, {time: 1.0, transition: Equations.easeNone, alpha: 0.0});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap bit looks as simple as it can get to me, but you could try to use a different tween library like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), sometimes there are huge performance differences.

If that doesn't help, it might be that the AIR window transparency performance is the problem, in which case you could fudge it by trying to take a bitmap snapshot of what's behind the window and crossfade with that as another bitmap internally.

Comment: i'm almost certain it's not Tweener causing the poor performance since the fade is fine if the window is small - if the faderBitmap is small.  in fact, i get the same performance if i don't rasterize the faderFill graphic at all, leaving it as a vector graphic.

Comment: Try TweenLite anyway, Greensock's work is pretty good and it'll probably save a few KB.

Comment: Well, since the vector shape is super simple, I guess rendering it as bitmap is negligible time and it's the compositing pass which kills performance. Seems that you might have to try faking it as I wrote in my second paragraph. Or actually before that try to see if there's any hardware rendering issue (either by it being on or off), try it on different PCs and make sure that your video card drivers are up to date.

Comment: @shanethehat - TweenLite isn't free, and i can't justify spending $150/year on a tweening library to possibly save a few KB and a claim to a performance increase.

@dain - i'm on a pretty fast Mac, even though it's still a mac so it might be faster on a PC.  testing different hardware acceleration settings in Flash CS5 Publish Settings showed no change.  i think you might be right about the snapshot.  when under the fade is only other bitmaps, the performance is much better, but when there exists vector graphics it's choppy, even though i'm not altering the vector graphics' alpha. expected?

Comment: Strange, I'd expect those vectors underneath to be cached if nothing changes with them. They definitely need to be composited when you're doing an alpha fade on top of them, but the expected behaviour would be for Flash to just reuse their rendered bitmap representation. Re TweenLite, unless you're redistributing the code itself or making a Flash component you don't have to pay.

Comment: actually, i was wrong.  there is no performance increase after all - there was for a while but then it went back to being choppy again, or maybe i just imagined it was better?  FlashLite license states that if i'm producing work for sale (ie: commercial applications, 99¢ mobile apps) i require a corporate license, $150/year for a single developer.

Comment: it seems my problem is caused by AIR since it runs very smoothly with the Standalone Flash Player.  i've posted a new question with program attached:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728582/why-is-air-desktop-application-slower-than-standalone-flash-player